# Are antiderivative functions closed under products?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two function from reals to reals, such that both $f$ and $g$ have antiderivatives. Must their product $f*g$ also have antiderivatives? We can't simply use an antiderivative product rule, because no such rule exists.

Comment: What operation is $*$?

Comment: @Filippo User says "their product"...

Comment: @coffeemath I know, but there are many products. In fact I asked because I am used to $f*g$ being the involution.

Comment: As user notes  "can't use an antiderivative product rule" it would seem to be the usual product of two functions via product in the reals.

Comment: @Filippo It is the pointwise multiplication of two functions.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak No, there is no product rule. Integration by parts doesn't count, because in the formula, it uses the integral of a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in the realm of continuous functions, then every continuous function $f$ has an antiderivative $F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.  Since a product of continuous functions is still continuous, the product still has an antiderivative, though finding a simple formula for the antiderivative of the product using only a formula for the original functions and their antiderivatives may be difficult or impossible.

In the more general realm of functions that have continuous antiderivatives in the sense that $F'=f$ almost everywhere, and such that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds (i.e, $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(a)$), such functions $f$ must be locally integrable, and this condition is NOT preserved by multiplication.  Consider $$f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} & x\neq 0\text{,}\\
0 & x=0\text{,}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ has an antiderivative

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{x} & x\geq 0\text{,}\\
-2\sqrt{-x} & x<0\text{,}
\end{cases}
$$
but
$$f(x)g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{|x|} & x\neq 0\text{,}\\
0 & x=0\text{,}
\end{cases}
$$
which has no antiderivative in this sense, as it fails to be locally integrable at $x=0$.